# Disable notifications when updating a card.

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I made an app using the Mirror API and my idea was to allow the user to pin a card then send changes using the update option once a minute. It works great, but each update makes a noise which is very annoying.

Is there a way to disable the notification? I feel like with updates you should have the option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `timeline.update`, then the new card you send should just leave out the notification field. You don't indicate what language you're using, but the representation would be something like

```
{
  "text": "hello world"
}
```

(You can set the notification field, as shown below, but it isn't necessary.)

If you're using `timeline.patch`, then you should make sure you explicitly set the notification field to NULL.

```
{
  "text": "hello world",
  "notification": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're generating the /timeline/insert JSON, don't send a "**notification**" object and it will be sent to Glass without a noise.

https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/insert

> Controls how notifications for this item are presented on the device. If this is missing, no notification will be generated.